# Definite Integral-What is the most efficient way to integrate this?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is the most efficient way to integrate this expression?
I couldn't find any way?![enter image description here][1]

$$\int_2^4 \frac{x^2+x}{\sqrt{2x+1}}\,dx$$

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for help with formatting mathematics. There is an issue with this post, which is that it is an isolated problem statement. We look for questions that include *context*: where did you encounter the problem? What have you tried? You can edit the post to include this kind of information.

Answer (score 3):

Set $x^2+x=(x/2)(2x+1)+(1/4)(2x+1)-1/4$:

So:
$$I=\int_2^4\left(\frac x2\sqrt{2x+1}+\frac14\sqrt{2x+1}-\frac14(2x+1)^{-1/2}\right)dx\\
=\int_2^4\left(\frac 12\sqrt{2(x+1/4)^2-1/8}+\frac14\sqrt{2x+1}-\frac14(2x+1)^{-1/2}\right)dx$$

Use standard formulae now.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

How about setting $\sqrt{2x+1}=u\implies\dfrac{2dx}{\sqrt{2x+1}}=du$

and $x=(u^2-1)/2$